# Erro de importação ao enviar e-mail simples com python

Tags: python, python-3.x, email, envio-de-email

Estou aprendendo a enviar e-mail em python e estou me deparando com vários problemas. Um deles é já na importação do módulo smtplib. Meu código é o seguinte:

```
from smtplib import SMTP
smtp=SMTP('smtp.live.com',587)
smtp.starttls()
smtp.login('my@hotmail.com','senha')
msg='ola mundo'
smtp.sendmail('my@hotmail.com',['other@hotmail.com'],msg)
smtp.quit()
```

Este script gera o seguinte erro:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Benedito\Desktop\email.py", line 1, in <module>
    from smtplib import SMTP
  File "C:\Users\Benedito\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35- 32\lib\smtplib.py", line 47, in <module>
    import email.utils
  File "C:\Users\Benedito\Desktop\email.py", line 1, in <module>
    from smtplib import SMTP
ImportError: cannot import name 'SMTP'
```

Pelo que eu entendo, o erro trata o módulo smtplib como se ele não tivesse o método SMTP nele. Porém, quando executo a importação direto na linha de comando do Python, esse erro de importação não ocorre. Porque está dando erro quando executo um script e não está dando erro quando executo escrevendo linha por linha na linha de comando do python?

Estou no Windows 8 e uso Python 3.5.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Troque o nome do teu arquivo de `email.py` para `enviaremail.py` (ou qualquer coisa), ele parece estar conflitando com o `import email.utils` (usado pela lib `SMTP`)

E depois tente:

```
python enviaremail.py
```

É sempre bom evitar estes nomes para não conflitar com as classes e namespaces nativos