# Erro ao enviar e-mail simples com python

Tags: python, email, envio-de-email, ssl, smtp

Estou aprendendo a enviar e-mails com python. Logo no início, me deparei com erro de importação dos métodos do módulo smtplib, que gerou essa pergunta:

[Erro de importação ao enviar e-mail simples com python](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/174142/erro-de-importa%C3%A7%C3%A3o-ao-enviar-e-mail-simples-com-python)

Então vi que não dava erro de importação quando digitava comando por comando na linha de comando do python. Porém outro erro ocorreu. Esses são os comandos que digito linha por linha:

```
from smtplib import SMTP_SSL
server=SMTP_SSL('smtp.live.com',465)
```

Já nessa segunda linha, ocorre o seguinte erro:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#1>", line 1, in <module>
    server=SMTP_SSL('smtp.live.com',465)
  File "C:\Users\Benedito\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\smtplib.py", line 1021, in __init__
    source_address)
  File "C:\Users\Benedito\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\smtplib.py", line 251, in __init__
    (code, msg) = self.connect(host, port)
  File "C:\Users\Benedito\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\smtplib.py", line 335, in connect
    self.sock = self._get_socket(host, port, self.timeout)
  File "C:\Users\Benedito\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\smtplib.py", line 1027, in _get_socket
    self.source_address)
  File "C:\Users\Benedito\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\socket.py", line 711, in create_connection
    raise err
  File "C:\Users\Benedito\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\socket.py", line 702, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)
OSError: [WinError 10013] Foi feita uma tentativa de acesso a um soquete de uma maneira que é proibida pelas permissões de acesso
```

Como conserto esse erro? Alguém tem algum scrit que funcione que envie e-mail com python?

Answer (score 1):

Conforme esta [resposta no SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2779304/1518921) é porque no Windows é necessário o privilégio de administrador UAC, para resolver isto clique com direito do mouse no cmd.exe e selecione a opção <kbd>Executar como Administrador</kbd> e então tente executar o script:

```
python enviaremail.py
```

O prompt deve mostrar isto:

[image: prompt]

Se ainda falhar, pode ser que não seja os privilégios, mas sim um antivirus que bloqueia este método por ser envio em massa. Notei que você também instalou o Python na pasta de usuário ao invés da pasta *Programs And Files*, talvez isto impeça alguns acessos (verifique se o python.exe está liberado no Firewall também)

Comment: Infelizmente, a permissão de administrador não corrigiu o problema. Desativei o antivirus e também não obtive resultado. Python

Comment: @Benedito como está o windows update? Tentou reinstalar o Python na "arquivos de programas" (Programs And Files) como eu citei?

Comment: Instalei Python de forma padrão, logo ele mesmo se pôs nesta pasta. Mas já uso a algum tempo e nunca deu problema ele estar nesta pasta. E ele está liberado pelo Firewall também. Inclusive, consegui enviar e-mail por TLS, usando o método smtplib.SMTP. Só esse smtplib.SMTP_SSL está dando erro.

Comment: Atualizações automáticas sempre ativas, para baixar e instalar.

Comment: @Benedito tenho quase certeza que o endereço smtp.live.com só aceita TLS e não SSL.

Comment: E sabes algum que é aceito?

Comment: @Benedito acredito que a maioria hoje use o TLS, mas por desencargo de consciência seria legal verificar se o teu Python tem SSL instalado.